# Linux sort utility, possible to sort on minimum value of multiple columns?

Tags: linux, sorting

A text file has multiple columns of which one is "start" and the other "end", both holding positive integer values.  However, since the objects described (think of them as vectors placed on the number line) have a direction these can end up in either orientation like this:

```
 400  20  (start at 400, end at 20)
  10 100  (start at 10, end at 100 )
 300  15  (start at 300, end at 15)
```

Often one would like to order these by ranges, as opposed to start or end value.  The range limits for a row are:(min(start,end), max(start,end)). 
So sorting by the lower limit would give this order:

```
  10 100  (start at 10, end at 100 )
 300  15  (start at 300, end at 15)
 400  20  (start at 400, end at 20)
```

This type of sort can be accomplished using Perl or any other similar scripting language, first generating the lower range limit, and then sorting on it.  However, as far as I can tell there is no way to do this directly using the usual unix/linux sort utility.  Specifying something like this:

```
sort -k 1,1n -k 2,2n
```

sorts on the first, then if there is a tie, it sorts on the second.  That isn't the desired sort though.

Is there a way to do this type of "minimum of multiple column" sort using just "sort"?

Comment: only sort in the sense of no awk, bash built-ins, or other common commandline tools...?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do it with just `sort`.